# Rest API - Online partial refund with multiple products error

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.0, rest-api, paypal, refund

I want to partial refund (for example 5$) with the rest API for an invoice paid with PayPal.

I am using this endpoint: /invoice/{id}/refund 
And this body:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 1,
      "qty": 0
    }
  ],
  "isOnline": true,
  "arguments": {
    "shipping_amount": 0,
    "adjustment_positive": 5
  }
}
```

**It works, if the customer bought only one product.**

But it gives me the following error if the customer bought multiple products (same body, but more products bought ... tried it also with all order_item_id's and I don't want to set qty to 1 because then the product itself will be invoiced, I just want to refund e.g. 5$)

> "Creditmemo Document Validation Error(s):\nYou can't create a creditmemo without products."

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just an error from the API?